# Merge array key values - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Hi all i need to merge the same key to convert to single array from multiple array list please any one help me to the problem

for example here the array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mr.
            [1] => Mrs.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Rob
            [1] => Tam
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => kar
            [1] => Man
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 55345345345
            [1] => 44545345435
        )

)
```

i need the output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mr.
            [1] => Rob
            [2] => kar
            [3] => 55345345345
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mrs.
            [1] => Tam
            [2] => Man
            [3] => 44545345435
        )

)
```

Please any one help

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = array(
    0 => array(
        0 => 'Mr.',
        1 => 'Mrs.'
    ),

    1 => array
    (
        0 => 'Rob',
        1 => 'Tam'
    ),

    2 => array
    (
        0 => 'kar',
        1 => 'Man'
    ),

    3 => array
    (
        0 => 55345345345,
        1 => 44545345435
    )
);

$arr1 = array();
foreach($a as $arr)
{
    foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
    {
        $arr1[$key][] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($arr1);
```

Use this one. You can get output same as you want.

Answer (score 3):

For `PHP version >= 5.5.0` You can use [**`array_column()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [**`array_merge()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) for this as

```
$result = array_merge(array_column($records, '0'), array_column($records, '1'));
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Or just `[array_column($records, '0'), array_column($records, '1')]`

Comment: Yaa this is also an optimize solution!!@Thamilan

Comment: You need to specify that the above code works on PHP version >= 5.5.0

Comment: Yep I mention it into answer!! @Uchiha

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
$out = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value){
    $out[] = (object)array_merge((array)$arr2[$key], (array)$value);
}
print_r($out)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$title = $array[0];
$firstname = $array[1];
$lastname = $array[2];
$number = $array[3];
$output = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($title); $i++)
{
  $output[] = array($title[$i],$firstname[$i],$lastname[$i],$number[$i])
}
var_dump($output);
```